# smbclient "NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND getting alt name for \" on Windows Server 2012 shares

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012, samba, network-share, smbclient

I successfully connected to Windows Server 2012 SMB shares from a CentOS 7 host using the tool smbclient.

I can list files and browse directories from the W2012 shares, but when i submit the command 'allinfo filename' I am getting the error "NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND getting alt name for \" even if the file exist on the share.

Examples

```
smb: \> allinfo test.txt
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND getting alt name for \test.txt
smb: \> allinfo \
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND getting alt name for \
smb: \> allinfo ""
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND getting alt name for \
```

If i connect from the same host to different SMB shares on different hosts (I tried it connecting to a share on a Windows 10 host and to another share on a Western Digital NAS) everything works just fine like in the examples below

```
smb: \> allinfo test.txt
altname: test.txt
create_time:    dom set 29 11:47:33 2019 EDT
access_time:    dom set 29 11:47:33 2019 EDT
write_time:     dom set 29 11:47:41 2019 EDT
change_time:    dom set 29 11:47:41 2019 EDT
attributes:  (80)
stream: [::$DATA], 4 bytes
smb: \> allinfo ""
altname: .
create_time:    dom set 29 11:04:40 2019 CEST
access_time:    dom set 29 11:04:40 2019 CEST
write_time:     dom set 29 11:25:42 2019 CEST
change_time:    dom set 29 11:25:42 2019 CEST
attributes: D (10)
```

I believe the problem is related to how Windows Server 2012 is managing the shares.

Any idea??